# Can I search the elements of an object in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, list, element

So I have and ArrayList of objects (say Items) and i have another object(say user).
so I want to be able to search for equality (or other Booleans) between user.element and the arrays Item.element and would also like to be to recall and display information from the Item.element that rings true to the boolean.

I'd post code but its all a bunch of craziness that hasn't worked.

would i be better served to have the objects in a different kind of array?

if it matters the 2 objects  are descended from the same class
okay so this is what i have tried

```
public boolean isSomethingThere(GameObject user) {
    for(int i=0; i; i++) {
        if{theseWalls[i].position=user.position) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

also tried for the body
`if (theseWall.position.contains(user.position));`

i would also like to eventually in this be able to so the wall.name of the wall that was the same as the user

Comment: "bunch of craziness that hasn't worked". this resumes almost 20 years of my life ;-)

Comment: go ahead. post your bunch of craziness. everybody here started writing things like this, nobody can judge you

Comment: if there's always the same amount of users and items, there's some elegant ways to compute that if you put one item and one user in the same object and have a list of this object to process. If there isn't such cardinality, I recommend you to write some helper class just to process these two arrays (or lists) to return you the result, which is also a nice solution

Comment: they both need to beable to vary in number

Comment: Might want to take at your for loop condition `{i=0; i; i++)` to start with.

Comment: And it's `if (condition)`, not `if {condition)`. If you want to have access to the matching wall, then make your method return the matching wall, not a boolean. And the `[i]` operator can only be used on arrays, not on ArrayList.

Comment: That's one reason you should post the actual code (tidied up a bit, of course): typos like that are eliminated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a few of my games what i do is this:

```
Hero hero; //User
ArrayList<Aliens> aliens //ArrayList of enemies
```

Lets say I want to check if they are colliding!

```
for(i = 0; i < aliens.size(); i++){
    Aliens a = (Aliens) aliens.get(i);  // <-- This might be something you want to do
    if(hero.getBounds().intersects(a.getBounds())
        kill();
    else
        a.remove(i);
}
```

Now this is just an example but I am sure you should be able to use this in your program! I could help a bit more if you could provide more of your code!

Comment: yes thank you that is what i am looking for!  what is the .get(i) is that a function of ArrayList?

Comment: yes it is :) it gets the element at that index within the arraylist.